# Cannot edit data in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I put a project I have been working on in QGIS in QField (both using the cloud as well as transferring the project via USB using the QField plugin). I was able to load it in QField, but was not able to edit or even see the attribute table from my data points. I only see the symbols and labels but when I tap the points I don't see any of the information. In the configuration, I made sure all fields in the attribute table were editable, so I am not sure what more I can do. The geopackage with my data is also set to offline editing.
I also followed the first two lessons on https://livelihoods-and-landscapes.com/qgis_qfield_tutorials/training_overview.html, and had the same problem, even though I followed everything exactly as was described. I am using QGIS version 3.30.2 and the latest update of QField on my Fairphone 4.